# When zooming, background video doesnt stick

Tags: css, html, video, zooming

http://www.littlemountainmedia.co.uk

Just trying to get a video behind the header but when zooming in or out, the content on the rest of the page overflows the video.

Just wondering how to fix this as otherwise it is perfect

CSS for the video : http://pastebin.com/VX0ki1GF

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're trying to put a video IN FRONT OF header? Also, add width: 100%; to <video>

Comment: the webpage you added looks really bad in opera, can barely see the writing....think you should show a down arrow aswell to make it obvious to people there is more content below.